# How to solve this combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been trying to solve this combinatorial problem but couldn't solve it.
The problem is as follows:
If C(a,b) is the binomial coefficient then prove that
$$ C(n,0) + C(n,2) + C(n,4) +...+C(n,n) = C(n,1)+C(n,3)+C(n,5)+...+C(n,n-1)=\frac{2^n}{2}$$
I would really appreciate a step by step solution or at least a hint on how to solve it because I've been trying for days.

Comment: yes, I don't know how to write the binomial coefficient. I will edit the name

Comment: Hint. $(1+1)^n=2^n$, $(1-1)^n=0$.

Comment: Think about counting subsets.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried by writing 2^(n-1) as a sum. Then I got a sum with binomial coefficient but couldn't write it as the other sums

Comment: Probably been asked and answered here many times. I recommend a search.

Answer (score 2):

Call
$$x= C(n,0) + \dots + C(n,n)$$
and $$y= C(n,1) + \dots + C(n,n-1)$$
Then
$$x+y = \sum_{k=0}^n C(n,k)=2^n$$
and
$$x-y= \sum_{k=0}^n C(n,k) (-1)^k =0$$

Hence $x,y$ are the solutions of the system
$$\cases{ x+y=2^n \\ x-y=0}$$
which can be easily solved.

Comment: How do you deduce that x-y=0

Comment: $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n C(n,k) a^k b^{n-k}$. Set $a=-1$, $b=1$.
The solution and the question obviously presume that $n$ is even.

Comment: I see. Thank you